# How to form result of MatrixExp

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have this sets of equations:

system=$\left(\begin{array}{c} x1'(t)=x2(t)\\ x2'(t)=-p2(t)-x2(t)\\ p1'(t)=-x1(t)\\p2'(t)=p2(t)-p1(t)\\\end{array}\right)$

and corresponding $A$ matrix is

$\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\     0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\\end{array}\right)$

I need to find the solution and have with the following line;

```
(Simplify /@ MatrixExp[t A] // N)
```

which resulted ie the 1,1 element of result as

$0.5 \left((0.5\, -0.288675 i) e^{(0.866025\, -0.5 i) t}+(0.5\, -0.288675 i) e^{(-0.866025+0.5 i) t}+(0.5\, +0.288675 i) e^{(-0.866025-0.5 i) t}+(0.5\, +0.288675 i) e^{(0.866025\, +0.5 i) t}\right)$

**Edit: Required Codes**

```
A = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 1}};

(Simplify /@ MatrixExp[t A] // N) // TableForm
```

where $t$ is time variable.

How can I get rid of the imaginary variable inside the parenthesis and the exponential form to get something like $c_1e^a\cos(b)+c_2e^a\sin(b))$?

Result should be like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp%20(t%20%7B%7B0,1,0,0%7D,%7B0,-1,0,-1%7D,%7B-1,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,-1,1%7D%7D)).

Comment: You've already asked a few questions so should be able to format them properly.  Here, you're mixing $\LaTeX$, code, and uncompiled $\LaTeX$ (?!). Edit your post so that it's readable. Provide the codes required to reproduce your results. As it stands, there's no `t` or `A`. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for basic tips on asking questions. I'll retract the downvote once you conform to the requirements.

Comment: Look up `ExpToTrig[]` in the meantime.

Comment: @corey979 it was readable format for $\latex$ but it doesn't allow me to submit the question saying it seems there is a unporper formatted code. Thus I changed them into code to  be able to submit.

Comment: :) yes t is free variable. So how to solve :)

Comment: may be it is a style thing, but I find `Simplify[ MatrixExp[t A] ]` more clear than `Simplify /@ MatrixExp[t A]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
m = Simplify /@ MatrixExp[t A] // Normal
```

do either (this gives hyperbolic functions)

```
out1 = FullSimplify @ ExpToTrig @ m
out1[[1, 1]]
```

> $\cos \left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}\right)-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$

or (to get exponentials)

```
out2 = FullSimplify @ ComplexExpand @ m
out2[[1, 1]]
```

> $\frac{e^{-\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}} \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{e^{\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}} \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}} \cos
>    \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$

(I show only one element of each output because they're long).

Comment: One might want to pre-process the `RootSum[]` objects with `Normal[]` before feeding to `ExpToTrig[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Nice one, thanks!

Comment: @corey979 thank you.